# mysql get free spots in query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following structure in a database

> Tent(id, numberOfSpots)
>
> Person(id, name, tentId)

## Tent

```
+----+---------------+
| id | numberOfSpots |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |             5 |
|  2 |             3 |
|    |               |
+----+---------------+
```

## Person

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id |   name   | tentId |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 | Simon    |      1 |
|  2 | Jasmin   |      1 |
|  3 | Markus   |      1 |
|  4 | Romy     |      1 |
|  5 | Fabrizia |      1 |
|    |          |        |
+----+----------+--------+
```

## Query

I want a query, that gets the next tentId which has a free spot available.
So with the example data above, it would be `tentId = 2`. If there would be one less person, it would be `tentId = 1`

I've come up with something like this:

```
select t.Id
from Tent as t
left join (
    select p.tentId, count(*) as occupiedSpots
    from person as p
    group by p.tentId) as i ON i.tentId = t.id
where z.numberOfSpots > i.occupiedSpots
```

but i don't get a result...

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: really, you want first tentid, is not present in Person but is in Tent?

Comment: i want the first tentid that has *less* relationships to persons than numberOfSpots

Comment: @xeraphim Who is z as alias ?

Comment: z = t sorry i forgot to change this while translating to english :)

Comment: Then edit the query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test if null value in `occupiedSpots`

```
select t.Id
from Tent as t
left join (
    select p.tentId, count(*) as occupiedSpots
    from person as p
    group by p.tentId) as i ON i.tentId = z.id
where t.numberOfSpots > IFNULL(i.occupiedSpots,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding a sub query, you should be able to do something like this:-

```
SELECT tent.id, tent.numberOfSpots - COUNT(person.id) AS free_places
FROM tent
LEFT OUTER JOIN person
ON tend.id = person.tendId
GROUP BY tent.id
HAVING free_places > 0
```

Get a count of the people per tent and subtract that from the tent capacity. And use a HAVING clause to return those with more than zero spaces